# true circle (or any non-rectangle shape) element in html5?

Tags: html, css, element, geometry

I haven't seen any documentation on them, so they probably don't exist, but it's always good to check.

I'm looking for a truly-circular (or polygon of any type other than rectangle) element. I can draw a circle in canvas, but the canvas is still a rectangle. I can draw a circle using border-radius, but it's still a square element with pretty round corners.

I'm looking for an (easy) way to make complex shape buttons that are very precise on their clickable areas.

My current method is to use JavaScript, listen to clicks and measure position. It would be much more ideal if this were handled in html5/css3.

Comment: imagemap may fit the bill, but it is way old for your question...

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/examples/RoundButtons/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Border-radius just makes the element look round (except in firefox, reportedly).

Maps kind of work, but I want to avoid forcing an image.

SVG works, but it's still not pure html/css because javascript is needed for links to work. The SVG element is still square too, though the shapes inside are elements that respond well to javascript events. So it's not 100% perfect, but it is workable.

Would definitely be cooler if we had the ability to control the shape of elements on the page beyond drawing inside of a canvas. Maybe I'll play around with building an entire site inside a canvas...

Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

Well, all elements start as a block, square or rectangle in one shape form or another. Outside of that through CSS you manipulate the block, to appear as a circle. But its not to go without saying not all browsers support this fully, but its mostly the older browsers you have to worry about in that essence.

If your looking for something 100% compatible old and new, theres http://pixlr.com you can draw one there and use an image tag.. But even then the image is still square/rectangle. Theres really no escaping that notion any route you go.

All in all..

```
<div class="full-circle"></div>

.full-circle {
 background-color: #c06;
 border: 3px solid #333;
 height: 150px;
 border-radius:75px;
 -moz-border-radius:75px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 75px;
 width: 150px;
}
```

As far as your current method, thats the only plausible logic for the most part, doing things outside the "norm" usually requires a bit more work then a single line of code or three to do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

There are no truly circular elements, but try using a regular box element and using the CSS3 specification `border-radius`.  For example:

```
border-radius: 50px;
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
overflow: hidden;
```

This creates an element which is effectively circular, and Firebug respects the curved form when hovering over elements.